# Fundamentally, how is "the probability that two randomly selected samples belong to different classes" intuitively useful in any notion of purity?

Tags: machine-learning, cart, intuition

The Gini impurity measure is defined by

$$\sum_{i=1}^m f_i(1 - f_i)$$

This based on the probability of two randomly selected samples belonging to two different classes, one of which is $i$, i.e. $f_i(1 - f_i)$ - but how is this useful to our intuitive understanding of purity?

That is, can anyone provide an analogy or some other such mapping for why this measure says anything about the purity of a set?

Comment: This article gives a through justification for the various splitting criteria: https://www.benkuhn.net/tree-imp.  The short story is: you are greedily minimizing a loss function; the residual squared error in the case of Gini impurity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Gini impurity measure, $f_i$ is the proportion of items in the set that belong to class $i$.  Since $\sum f_i=1$, an alternative formula is
$$
1-\sum f_i^2\tag1
$$
How is this a measure of impurity? Certainly if the set consists of only one class, then (1) has value 0, which is as low as you can get. Conversely, if the set is totally heterogeneous, so that $f_i=\frac1m$ for each $i$, then (1) attains the maximum possible value of $1-\frac1m$. To see why this is the maximum possible, you can rewrite (1) in the form
$$
1-\frac1m - \sum\left(f_i-\frac1m\right)^2\tag2
$$
which also demonstrates that the only time the max is achieved is when all classes are equally represented.

There are other ways to measure heterogeneity of a set. What is desired is some numeric score that allows us to rank order the possible splits. So for example you could calculate the **entropy** of the frequency distribution:
$$
-\sum f_i\log(f_i)\tag3
$$
Note that (3) is computationally more expensive than (1), which is maybe why CART decided to adopt Gini impurity over entropy. But note the two measures are roughly the same, owing to the approximation $\log(x)\sim x-1$.

Comment: This is an explanation of what the Gini impurity is. I was looking for a way to intuitively explain why it works as a measure of impurity. Essentially, a way to derive it from somewhere close to first principles. However it looks like that isn't going to be possible since this is a complex topic.

Comment: @naiveai It is possible to derive it from deeper principles, please see the article I posted as a comment to your question.

Comment: @naiveai If a set is pure, then randomly sampling twice (with replacement) from that set is never going to get two items from different classes. OTOH if the set is heterogeneous ("totally not pure") you are quite likely to see two items from the same class, more so if there are many possible classes: the probability is $1-\frac1m$ as shown above. I am not sure if this is your question, or whether you are looking for a derivation of $P(\text{two different classes})=\sum f_i(1-f_i)$

Answer (score 0):

In terms of intuition, it measures the impurity because it kind of measures how less confident you are about the sample belonging to one class. Thus, if $f_i$ is close to $0$ or $1$, then you are highly confident about the assignment and thus the impurity is low. If the value is to $0.5$ instead then the Gini impurity is maximum ($=1/4$).

You would see similar expression in the variance of a Bernoulli random variable. If $p$ is the probability that the random variable takes the value $1$ then the variance is given by $p(1-p)$. Although, in this case its an actual formula deduced by derivation (and not just intuition), but intuition is the same. If the value of $p$ are close to $0$ or $1$, you have low variance (as you are more confident whether it is $0$ or $1$).